# Integral representation for inner product in the Gupta-Bleuler quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, quantum-electrodynamics

Following the Gupta-Bleuler method for the quantization of the electromagnetic field, we have that:

$$[a_{k'\lambda'},\hat{a}^\dagger_{k\lambda}]=-g_{\lambda \lambda'}\delta(k-k')$$
And the vacuum
$$\hat{a}_{k\lambda}| 0 \rangle= 0 \ , \ \ \forall \ k, \lambda $$

As usual the eigenstates of the occupation-number operators can be constructed by applying the creation operators to the vacuum. 
$$| n_{k\lambda} \rangle= \frac{1}{\sqrt{n_{k\lambda}}}(\hat{a}^\dagger_{k\lambda})^{n_{k\lambda}}| 0 \rangle $$
So, we have that the norm of the one-photon state is
$$\langle n_{k\lambda} | n_{k\lambda} \rangle= \langle 0 |\hat{a}_{k\lambda}\hat{a}^\dagger_{k\lambda}| 0 \rangle 
$$

$$
\langle 1_{k\lambda} | 1_{k\lambda} \rangle= \langle 0 |-g_{\lambda\lambda}\delta(k-k)+\hat{a}^\dagger_{k\lambda}\hat{a}_{k\lambda}| 0 \rangle =
 -g_{\lambda\lambda}\delta(0)\langle 0| 0 \rangle 
$$
Since $g_{00}=+1$ you can see that $\langle 1_{k 0} | 1_{k 0} \rangle$ is negative.

Now, I would like to find and integral representation for that inner product in the same spirit as $\int f(x)^*g(x)dx$ in undergraduate quantum mechanics.
I think we can use the decomposition of the identity:
$$
\hat{I}=\int \mu (k)d^3 k|k\rangle\langle k|
$$
The function $\mu (k)$ could be $\mu(k)\sim \frac{1}{|k|}$.
$$
\langle 1_{k\lambda} | 1_{k\lambda} \rangle=\int \mu (k)d^3 k\langle 1_{k\lambda}|k\rangle\langle k|1_{k\lambda} \rangle
$$

$$
\langle k|1_{k\lambda} \rangle=f(k) \ , \ \ \langle 1_{k\lambda}|k\rangle=f(k)^*
$$

We have now that $f^*f=|f|^2\geq0$, so it seems that $\langle 1_{k\lambda} | 1_{k\lambda} \rangle$ is always positive.

I expect to have an integral that  gives a negative number for $\lambda=0$
 and positive for $\lambda=1,2,3$.

What is wrong here?

What is the right integral representation of the norm/inner product?